# How to update tables with nvarchar(max) columns with minimal locks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have trouble to update some rows in SQL Server (2005 and 2008).

Often, when I try to update one row while having a running query (`select * from thistable`),
I start the update command and it will fail due to a timeout/lock issue.

It only appears on tables with `nvarchar(max)/text` columns!

Even if I try to `SELECT * FROM thistable WITH(ROWLOCK)`, I do encounter the same problem.

So my basic question here is:

*Can I motivate SQL Server NOT to lock more than the actual row ?*

Edit: I first run the SELECT afterwards I try to UPDATE...

---

There is a great explanation on Locking in SQL-Server [on simple talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/handling-deadlocks-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @marc_s: why do I get those locks doing ONE update ?

Comment: @marc_s: so you don't have a solution for me ?

Comment: @marc_s: I think you did not understand my problem. I do only update ONE (1) row and I can not do it, because the select did not allow it. On tables without text-columns I do not have any problems.

Comment: Read committed is Database Engine default isolation level. So, you lock all your table by SELECT. You can try hint (nolock) your SELECT, but you can have problem with "dirty read" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190805.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
SELECT * FROM thistable (NOLOCK)
```

for your select statement.

Then run your update as normal.

Comment: will give this a try (sadly it involves changing the update-command-builder machanism)

Comment: I hear you there, it's a pain when you have to go to those lengths.  We had an in house policy at the last place I worked where ALL select statements where done using NOLOCK, the DBA was allowed to hunt you down if you didn't :-)

Comment: I can't thank you enough ! I will try to use another SQL-Server next time :-(  NOLOCK for the queries did the trick (finally)  +1 for your DBA (sadly)